# Can regression be used with 3 observations and more than 3 independent variables?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-regression

I want to regress `v1` on `o1:o7`.  I would like to do the same for each of `v2:v5` with `o1:o7`.  Is this possible?

Comment: You can run regression on anything you want, but 3 rows is not going to give you a very accurate model.  With so little data, it is even hard to reduce the number of variables.  You might consider resampling the data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum number of independent variables that can be entered into a multiple regression equation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12854/maximum-number-of-independent-variables-that-can-be-entered-into-a-multiple-regr)

Comment: This is a rather extreme large $p$ small $n$ problem. See also [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108614/regression-in-pn-setting-how-to-choose-regularization-method-lasso-pls-pc).

Comment: Please read degrees of freedom

Answer (score 1):

An excellent and very comprehensive answer has been given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12854/maximum-number-of-independent-variables-that-can-be-entered-into-a-multiple-regr) to a related question.  In summary, given the low number of samples, you will suffer from an inability to estimate parameters in a multiple regression.  To estimate all the parameters, you will need k+2 samples to get parameter estimates with confidence intervals, or at least 9 samples for 7 predictors.

To your more general question of "can regression be of help", I would recommend you refine what exactly you mean.  Do you mean help to predict v1 for new samples?  Do you mean estimating parameters with a certain level of confidence?  Etc.  I think you will find better quality assistance with a more refined question.

Comment: (+1) Especially for the 2nd paragraph - a precise statement of modelling goals needs to precede any discussion of e.g. regularization techniques.